# Where does "Bluetooth and other devices" get its information from?

Tags: winapi, usb, hid

I am writing C++ code for listing USB HID devices that uses `HidD_GetProductString()`. One particular device, despite the function's success, returns an empty string.

The classic *Device Manager* and *gwmi* in *PowerShell* both list the device using a generic name. However, Windows 10 Immersive Control Panel's **Bluetooth and other devices** window lists this device with its actual full name, which does not seem to appear anywhere. I did not find it in the registry either. I want to get access to this information.

Does anyone know where this app gets its information from?

My suspicion is that it gets it directly from the *System* process, which is also a holder of an open file handle to a device file, and perhaps it is the reason why the function returns an empty output. If so, how could I do it? Any suggestion is appreciated...

Comment: Are you sure the question you asked is the question you meant to ask? Is a hypothetical answer going to help you solve the problem you ultimately want to solve?

Comment: I think it is the right question. I believe I have sufficient technical knowledge to use this information (I have written device drivers in the past), so a speculative guess is not what I am looking for. I am either trying to figure out how to get a non-empty string from the aforementioned function, or where does the operating system offers this description.

Comment: In other words, the *real* question is: "How does the system expose USB HID devices' product strings?"

Comment: No really. According to [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getproductstring), the system exposes USB HID devices' product strings through `HidD_GetProductString()`. This works for **nearly** all devices; in my system this does not work for a certain 3rd party input controller and the keyboard. Other devices are reported correctly, as they should. Also, the system behaves as if it did work (no errors returned), but produces empty strings - this behaviour is not documented, and the Immersive Control Panel seems to somehow bypass it.

Comment: The "Immersive Control Panel" presumably accesses the Windows Runtime API instead of the flat Win32 API.

Comment: Thank you; you are absolutely right. I blindly assumed that WinRT only provides an abstraction around the same API. I tested your suggestion and indeed Win32 and WinRT give me different lists of devices, solving my problem. Please post an answer so that I can accept it.